# How to show that $\int_{\delta D} x\ dx $ is area of $D$

Tags: integration, proof-writing

**Prove  that  $\int_{\delta D}x\ dy$  is  area  of  the  $D$  and $\int_{\delta D}y\ dx$   is  munis  the  area  of  $D.$**

Now  using  **Green's Theorem**  I  can  prove  that $$\int_{\delta D}x\ dy+\int_{\delta D}y\ dx\ =\ 0$$ so  the  second  part  is  readily  done.

But  problem  is  proving  that $\int_{\delta D}x\ dy$  is the  area. By  definition , $$\int_{\delta D}x\ dy=lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\sum_{i=1}^n (x_{j+1})(y_{j+1}-y_j).$$
Now drawing  pictures , *and considering $x$ to be a  function of $y$*, I  can see the  *sum*  on  the  right  tends  to  the  area  under  the  curve  but  I  cannot  write  the  proof  analytically.

Thanks  for  any  help.

Comment: How would you like to define the area?  One way would be $\iint_D\,dx\,dy$. The result then also follows from Green's theorem: 
$$\int_{\partial D} x\, dy = \iint_D 1\, dx\,dy.$$

Comment: @JamesM : So  its  all  about  the  definition  then $?$ .  If  I  define  area  as   you  did  ,  it  was  really  a  trivial  problem  then. ok thanks.

Comment: Now that you have the key in your hand, I suggest that you write an answer to this question, and accept it, so that it won't go into the "list of never ending questions"...